# FlowJS and function with 2 signatures and optional parameter

Tags: flowtype, intersection

How do I precisely type in Flow the following function that either takes a callback and call it later with some value or takes no arguments and return a Promise for that value?

```
const foo = callback => {
    const p = Promise.resolve(1.0);
    if (callback === undefined) {
      return p;
    }
    p.then(callback);
  }
};
```

I tried to use an intersection type like in:

```
type CallbackCase = ((number) => void) => void;
type PromiseCase = () => Promise<number>;

const foo: CallbackCase & PromiseCase = 
  callback => {
    const p = Promise.resolve(1.0);
    if (callback === undefined) {
      return p;
    }
    p.then(callback);
  };
```

But then Flow complains (this is also so with the latest version at https://flow.org/try):

```
Cannot assign function to `foo` because undefined [1] is incompatible with `Promise` [2] in the return value. [incompatible-type]
```

So how can I fix this?

Update: The reason for this signature is that we have older code where the function was taking a callback. We would like to convert it to the promise form while still supporting older callers. During the conversion we would like to keep the types precise. In particular at the call site only the two forms should be allowed:

```
let a: Promise<number> = foo();
foo(callback);
```

Any other forms should be rejected.

Comment: Link to flow try reports no errors, so all good? )

Answer (score 0):

You can specify argument as a function

```
type Callback = <T>(T) => void;

const foo = 
  (callback:Callback) => {
    const p = Promise.resolve(1.0);
    if (callback === undefined) {
      return p;
    }
    p.then(callback);
  };
```

seems to [works well](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNZQLxQDwAqAfABQECUORUAbgPYCWAJgNwBQbadAdgM7BQAZnTo4obKFBJpEKdBgBc8JKkyVs1AN4TJULnwFgxABQBOdALYNeEAHSmIvOghoQSARlsAGcu11QGQSkZFXkcbFwAV24mCEEGbggmSm1-SQdgSNNuKDA-XQBfHUkwW2AACwhuaVlVDF8dApYgA)

Comment: It does not even after using callback?: Callback as a parameter - https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNZQLxQDwAqAfABQECUORUAbgPYCWAJgNwBQbadAdgM7BQAZnTo4obKFBJpEKdBgD8ALnhJUmStmoBvCZKhc+AsGIAKAJzoBbBrwgA6cxF50ENCCQCM9gAzl2+lAMglIyavI42LgArtxMEIIM3BBMlLqBkk7A0ebcUGAB+gC+epJg9sAAFhDc0rLqGP56RexsCBACcEpQ3NFWyBDmYsJ0JE0jJCROvNEIwN29-YOaOgY8Lu32CHQA5lPOs8D+UEXkQA

Comment: @IgorBukanov in your example you return `void` since there is no `return` statement before `p.then(...)`. Not sure I get your idea, but something [like this](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNZQLxQHYCuAtshAE44B8+xpZA3AFCNoD2eAzsFAGaus4ojKFAAUaRCnQYA-AC54SVJgCUcqAAUyrIgEsOEADyES5atmoBvYSKhtO3MIK079EAHRkIHVggBuEKIAjO4ADCpMtlC6PGISStI42LgEeAAmEDy6eBBpKlDWUSJewARkeFBgkbYAvjbFEKXlle7AABYQeOKSyhgRNjVMjAiNUHDqLnoGxrRmgnysov0LoqJeHAQIwOomdPkWBUIi9j4j7gisAOZr3pvAEUdQJWUV63f0Iow1EUA) works well.

Comment: That allows nonce forms like let b: Promise<number> = foo(result => result). I updated the question to clarify. Basically, the type should allow to use the code either with the callback returning void with the void result from foo or as a promise form with no arguments to foo. Intersection type is ideal for that. But for some reason it does not work.